# Add an element ({"elem":"value"}) in each dictionary of a list, where value is a variable

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I need to add an each value of stock_quantity to each dict in a list (stock_info).

```
print (stock_info)
>>> [{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16}, {'symbol': 'AMZN', 'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61}, {'symbol': 'FB', 'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96}, {'symbol': 'GOOG', 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01}]

print (stock_quantity)
>>> [{'quantity': 20}, {'quantity': 20}, {'quantity': 30}, {'quantity': 20}]
```

As a result I want to see: (so quantity is inside the stock_info)

> > > [{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, ***'quantity': 20***}, {'symbol': 'AMZN', 'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61,*** 'quantity': 20***}, {'symbol': 'FB', 'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96, ***'quantity': 30***}, {'symbol': 'GOOG', 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01, ***'quantity': 20***}]

I tried this variant, but it does not work

```
i = 0
for item in stock_info:
    item.update ( { "quantity": "stock_quontity[i][quantity] "})
    i += 1
```

Because It actually append ***'quantity': 'stock_quontity[i][quantity] '***, but not the value of the stock_quontity[i][quantity]

Any help is greatly appreciated ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
for (i,d1), d2 in zip(enumerate(stock_info), stock_qty):
    d1.update(d2)
    stock_info[i]=d1

>>> stock_info
[{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, 'quantity': 20}, {'symbol': 'AMZN', 'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61, 'quantity': 20}, {'symbol': 'FB', 'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96, 'quantity': 30}, {'symbol': 'GOOG', 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01, 'quantity': 20}]
```

---

Explanation:

```
for (i,d1), d2 in zip(enumerate(stock_info), stock_qty)
 ^                                       for loop
      ^                                  unpack the tuple from enumerate     
          ^                              unpack the tuple from zip 
                   ^                     zip the two lists into pairs of elements
                        ^                enumerate the list we are changing

   d1.update(d2)
       ^                                 add d2 to d1

   stock_info[i]=d1
       ^                                 change the d1 in stock_info
   WARNING: careful changing lists you are interating over. 
   Don't change their length...
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Could you please briefly explain what is going on in your solution?

Comment: @wingedRuslan: Explantation added

Comment: Thanks! By the way, how is it possible to create a field called 'total' : value, where value = price * quantity? Something like {'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, 'quantity': 20, 'total' : 2903.2} Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661649/how-to-create-an-element-using-values-of-already-existed-elements-in-a-dict-ins)

Comment: just add that to `d2` before adding to `d1`