# How to create an element using values of already existed elements in a dict, inside a list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is my example:

```
print (stock_info)
>>> [{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, 'quantity': 20}, {'symbol': 'AMZN', 'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61, 'quantity': 20}, {'symbol': 'FB', 'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96, 'quantity': 30}, {'symbol': 'GOOG', 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01, 'quantity': 20}]
```

I have 'price' and 'quantity' fields with values.

And now I would like to create a field called 'total' = price * quantity

How to create a new field ('total': value) based on values of 2 fields, which already exist ( value = price * quantity)?

As a result I want to see:

```
>>> [{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, 'quantity': 20, 'total' : 2903.2}, {'symbol': 'AMZN', 'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61, 'quantity': 20, 'total' : 19972.2}, {'symbol': 'FB', 'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96, 'quantity': 30, 'total' : 4588.8}, {'symbol': 'GOOG', 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01, 'quantity': 20, 'total' : 19140.2}]
```

So each dict (dict, yes?)  was extended with a new field 'total' and its value.

How to implement this idea?

Any help is greatly appreciated ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through your data and add a new key to your dictionaries:

```
for stock_item in stock_info:
    stock_item["total"] = stock_item["price"] * stock_item["quantity"]
```

**EDIT** - Testing with your data:

```
stock_info = [{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, 'quantity': 20},
              {'symbol': 'AMZN', 'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61, 'quantity':20},
              {'symbol': 'FB', 'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96, 'quantity': 30},
              {'symbol': 'GOOG', 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01, 'quantity': 20}]

for stock_item in stock_info:
    stock_item["total"] = stock_item["price"] * stock_item["quantity"]

print(stock_info)
```

yields:

```
[{'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'price': 145.16, 'symbol': 'AAPL', 'total': 2903.2, 'quantity': 20},
 {'name': 'Amazon.com, Inc.', 'price': 998.61, 'symbol': 'AMZN', 'total': 19972.2, 'quantity': 20},
 {'name': 'Facebook, Inc.', 'price': 152.96, 'symbol': 'FB', 'total': 4588.8, 'quantity': 30},
 {'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'price': 957.01, 'symbol': 'GOOG', 'total': 19140.2, 'quantity': 20}]
```

Comment: Could you please be more accurate? In this way, only the last stock_item is stored. `{'total': 19049.102, 'quantity': 20, 'name': 'Alphabet Inc.', 'symbol': 'GOOG', 'price': 952.4551}` The output of stock_item

Comment: @wingedRuslan - you're checking it wrong then (I'm guessing you're printing `stock_item` instead of the `stock_info` list). `stock_item` is just a temporary reference, the real change happens in the nested `dict` items of your `stock_info` list. Check the example above.